# How to add tags to Buildbot EC2LatentBuildSlave

Tags: amazon-ec2, boto, buildbot

I am using EC2LatentBuildSlave to sawn EC2 instances running the build slaves. I would like to tag the slaves so a tag is visible in the EC2 dashboard Tags tab.

I am passing

```
tags={'Key':'BuildbotType', 'Value':'slaveName'}
```

but I can’t see the tags in the spawned EC2 instance.
Have I misunderstood this parameter?

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bug in buildbot version 0.8.12. Unfortunately we can't upgrade at this point. Instead I installed a init script (service) on the base AMI that reads user_data and tags its self. I pass the tag details using the user_data field in EC2LatentBuildSlave.

```
login_aws() {
  # Some code to configer aws access keys.
}

get_userdata() {
  AWS_USERDATA=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data)
  echo $AWS_USERDATA
}

tag_self_for_identification() {
  login_aws
  INSTANCE_ID=$(curl -s  http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
  if [ -z "$INSTANCE_ID" ]; then
    echo "Error unable to obtain instance id"
    return 0
  fi

  USERDATA=get_userdata
  set $USERDATA
  NAME="$2 $3"
  if [ ! -z "$NAME" ]; then
    echo "aws ec2 create-tags --resources $INSTANCE_ID --tags Key=Name,Value=$NAME"
    aws ec2 create-tags --resources $INSTANCE_ID --tags Key=Name,Value="$NAME" \
    Key=Buildbot,Value=Latentslave
  fi
}

tag_self_for_identification
```

This is an extremely over engineered solution. However I need tags to work for some lambda functions to be able to identify these latentlsaves